# Rank users in mysql by their points

Tags: mysql, sql, sorting, ranking, mysql-variables

I am trying to rank my students by their points that I've calculated before 
but the problem is if students have same points they both should be in same rank 
E.g

Student 1 has full points
Student 2 has full points

they both have to be rank as 1;

[image]
Here an example of my database

the query I am trying to do is (just for select then I can insert the values to my column)

```
 SELECT  a.points
        count(b.points)+1 as rank
FROM  examresults a left join examresults b on a.points>b.points
group by  a.points;
```

**Edit for being more clear:**

- Student 1 points 80
- Student 2 points 77.5
- Student 3 points 77.5
- Student 4 points 77

their ranks should be like

- Student 1 Rank 1
- Student 2 Rank 2
- Student 3 Rank 2
- Student 4 Rank 3

my current query returns a values like

[image]

As it is missing the third rank. (because second rank has 2 values)

Comment: let say student A and B has 20 points and C has 18, You want A and B be rank 1 and C rank 2 or 3?

Comment: A and B rank 1 and C rank 2

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is just a fix of Gordon solution using variables. The thing is your rank function isnt the way rank should work. (student 4 should be rank 4)

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ff872c/1)** *You can add more student to improve the testing.*

```
select er.*,
       (@rank := if(@points = points, 
                    @rank, 
                    if(@points := points,    
                       @rank + 1, 
                       @rank + 1                       
                      )
                   )                  
       ) as ranking
from students er cross join
     (select @rank := 0, @points := -1) params
order by points desc;
```

**OUTPUT**

```
| id | points | ranking |
|----|--------|---------|
|  1 |     80 |       1 |
|  2 |     78 |       2 |
|  3 |     78 |       2 |
|  4 |     77 |       3 |
|  5 |     66 |       4 |
|  6 |     66 |       4 |
|  7 |     66 |       4 |
|  8 |     15 |       5 |
```

Comment: This does a `dense_rank()`, rather than a rank.  So, it will return 1, 1, 1, 2, instead of 1, 1, 1, 4. . . . But that seems to be what the OP is asking for.

Comment: can you please do some modification to your query, if data has multiple rows for a same student and then we need to calculate the rank based on  the `sum` of all the points of that user. See this link for data http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/95dff ? thanks

Comment: @Sachin,  Sorry I dont understand, do you work with the OP and need a new requirement? I dont see OP say a student can have more than one point result

Comment: @Sachin If you need help with a similar but different problem just create a new question and I will help there just let me know. But I cant change this answer because is related to this question.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza, no problem. I've just created a new question, can you please look into that.. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34682333/rank-users-in-mysql-by-their-total-points-across-multiple-rows

Answer (score 1):

You want a real rank, which is calculated by the ANSI standard `rank()` function.  You can implement this in MySQL using this logic:

```
select er.*,
       (select 1 + count(*)
        from examresults er2
        where er2.points > er.points
       ) as ranking
from exampleresults er;
```

For larger tables, you can do this with variables, but it is a rather awkward:

```
select er.*,
       (@rank := if(@rn := @rn + 1              -- increment row number
                    if(@points = points, @rank, -- do not increment rank
                       if(@points := points,    -- set @points
                          @rn, @rn              -- otherwise use row number
                         )
                       )
                   )
       ) as ranking
from examresults er cross join
     (select @rn := 0, @rank := 0, @points := -1) params
order by points desc;
```

Answer (score 0):

this query achieve what do you want:

```
SELECT  student_id , points, (select count(distinct(points))+1 as rank 
from examresults internal 
where internal.points > external.points order by points)
FROM  examresults external 
group by  student_id
```

Comment: sorry still not working.  Expression #2 of SELECT list is not in GROUP BY clause and contains nonaggregated column 'onlineform_1.external.points' which is not functionally dependent on columns in GROUP BY clause; this is incompatible with sql_mode=only_full_group_by 

if I delete group by part then it messes up totally