# Why null values are not ranking same in mysql?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, null, ranking

Yesterday I asked a question about ranking students by their points.

[[Rank users in mysql by their points](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34637943/rank-users-in-mysql-by-their-points)
]

I actually solved my problem with the help I've recieved from other question (thanks to everyone who helped me).
Meanwhile I figured out something accidently. If I try to rank my students by their points and if  points column was empty (NULL) my query didn't gave an error also it sorted ranks like 1-2-3-4 but all values were **NULL**

this is the query I've tried

```
select er.*,
       (@rank := if(@points = points, 
                    @rank, 
                    if(@points := points,    
                       @rank + 1, 
                       @rank + 1                       
                      )
                   )                  
       ) as ranking
from examresults er cross join
     (select @rank := 0, @points := -1) params
order by points desc;
```

and this is the result.

[image]

So I wonder arent **NULL** values are the same ? isnt this query should gave **rank 1** for every user in my database ? why it ranks null values incrementally ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Many people think of `NULL` as meaning `no value` or `non-existent`. Even [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_%28SQL%29) explains it this way.

Think of it as `unknown value` and everything will make more sense.

One cannot compare two `unknown values` because, well, they are not known. They are not equal but they are also not different. None of them is greater than the other.

The result of comparison of two `unknown values` is also an `unknown value` (i.e. `NULL`).

Comment: impossible to argue with this answer! I think you need to edit the wikipedia post.

Comment: Well, for those patient enough to read, the Wikipedia page also says (in the third paragraph): *"SQL null is a state (unknown) and not a value."*.

Answer (score 2):

You compare `@points = points` which results in `@points=NULL`.

But any comparison to `NULL` results in `UNKNOWN`:

```
value= NULL -> UNKNOWN
value<>NULL -> UNKNOWN
value< NULL -> UNKNOWN
value> NULL -> UNKNOWN
```

Even `NULL=NULL` results in `UNKNOWN`.

Of course there are exceptions:

`DISTINCT` and `GROUP BY` consider NULLs equal.

Comment: Hi, then why I am not recieving an error such as you can't compare null with null ?

Comment: @Rodrane: Because you're not using a literal NULL, but a parameter and a column.

Comment: @Rodrane This is not error. Welcome to **[3-valued logic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_logic)**.

Comment: Great catch on the exceptions!

Answer (score 2):

NULL does not have a value - it is a state of non-existence. So any results based on NULL is non-deterministic. You should EXPLICITLY deal with the possibility of NULL values.

Answer (score 1):

Boolean comparison return true, false, or `NULL`, and `NULL` is generally treated as false.  You can easily modify your query to use `NULL`-safe equality:

```
select er.*,
       (@rank := if(@points <=> points, 
                    @rank, 
                    if(@points := points,    
                       @rank + 1, 
                       @rank + 1                       
                      )
                   )                  
       ) as ranking
from examresults er cross join
     (select @rank := 0, @points := -1) params
order by points desc;
```