# SQL Server Not(A=B and C=D) vs (A<> B or C<> D)

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a simple performance related question regarding Equality and Inequality. from the past experience I learnt that any Eq conditions work better and Or conditions cause some perf issues.

When I look at the query plan for both when executed side by side both had a **Scan type of EQ**

did same query plan. does it make a difference if I have the query formatted like `NOT(A=B and C=D)` or Just work with `(A <> B or C<> D)`

what is the best approach?

Did not think about nulls here, but here is the difference.

```
SELECT 1 WHERE NOT(2=1 AND NULL=2)
SELECT 1 WHERE NOT(2=1 AND 3=NULL)
SELECT 1 WHERE NOT(2=1 AND NULL=2)
SELECT 1 WHERE NOT(1=1 AND 3=NULL)
SELECT 1 WHERE NOT(NULL=1 AND 2=2)
SELECT 1 WHERE NOT(NULL=null AND 2=2)   --Point to note is his one. False, True
SELECT 1 WHERE NOT(1=1 AND 3=3)

SELECT 1 WHERE (2<>1 OR NULL<>2)
SELECT 1 WHERE (2<>1 OR 3<>NULL)
SELECT 1 WHERE (2<>1 OR NULL<>2)
SELECT 1 WHERE (1<>1 OR 3<>NULL)
SELECT 1 WHERE (NULL<>1 OR 2<>2)
SELECT 1 WHERE (NULL<>null or 2=2)      --Point to note is his one. True, True
SELECT 1 WHERE (1<>1 OR 3<>3)
```

Comment: Welcome to wonderful world of three-valued logic https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Three-valued_logic :-) Btw, your 2nd note should also read *False, True*

Comment: You should really be checking for NULL'ness by `x IS NULL` or `x IS NOT NULL` instead of comparing directly to `NULL` in statements like you edited into your question. *And* in tables, derived tables, common table expression or views, if there's a possibility of them containing `NULL` values you should always take extra care when you do comparisons eg in you `WHERE` clause, `JOIN` conditions etc.

Comment: @dnoeth http://stackoverflow.com/a/34654738/5070879 3rd comment :)

Comment: For SQL Server the most important things to know: A direct comparison with `NULL` yields the `UNKNOWN` value (an under the hood boolean value you can't directly check or compare with), and that `UNKNOWN <logic-op> {TRUE | FALSE | UNKNOWN}` yields `UNKNOWN` except when `<logic-op>=OR` and the other argument is `TRUE`. If you want to know more, [here](https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/learn-sql-server/sql-and-the-snare-of-three-valued-logic/) is an excellent article written Joe Celko.

Comment: So the only way is to put a  Where not ((isnull(a,'')= isnull(b,'') and isnull(c,'') = isnull(d,'')) This will sort the issue but will raise again the question of predicate having functions and will halt the server. it would be great if SqlServer gave a special function Called NullFalse(<expression>), because in C# (x=> !(x.a==x.b and x.c==x.d)) would give the desired result.

Comment: Oracle the query works like charm as no concept of nulls and  as long as strings were concerned

Answer (score 2):

For simple comparisons, I would expect these to have the same execution plans. `OR` tends to prevent the use of indexes.  However, it is unlikely that indexes would be used for not-equals.

Comment: `SELECT 1
WHERE NOT(NULL=1 AND 1=2)` => 1 **[Demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/424485)**

Comment: @lad2025 . . . Duh.  Sometimes, I can't reconstruct my thought processes.

Comment: @GordonLinoff  you pointed the null behaviour I did not even think about it, I will edit my post and put a sample as per lad2025